# How to change logo of tailwind css when using tailblocks?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailblocks to create a website but I don't know how to change the logo of tailwind CSS which comes built in. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55dcQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

search

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-10 h-10 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5"></path>
</svg>
```

and change it to what ever you want

[image]

Comment: How do i add my own logo link? where?

Comment: replace <svg ...> </svg> with <img src="youtlogoaddress.png">